# struts2 jfreechart plugin not running exectue method on action

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a action that creates a chart on a webpage via calling the action with

```
<img src=" <s:url action='generateChart' />" />
```

and that fires and calls the method defined in my bean file

```
<bean id="generateChart" class="com.action.electricity.CreateChart" scope="prototype">  
</bean>
```

which calls the class correctly

```
    private JFreeChart chart;

public String exectue() throws Exception{
    try{
        final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        chart = createChart(dataset, "My Chart");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

but it is giving me and error

```
No JFreeChart object found on the stack with name chart
```

the struts action is defined inside of its own package as

```
    <package name="graphs" namespace="/" extends="jfreechart-default">
    <action name="generateChart" class="generateChart">  
      <result name="success" type="chart">  
        <param name="width">400</param>  
        <param name="height">300</param>   
      </result>  
    </action>  
</package>
```

so the question becomes why is the chart always null. Which the answer is it never executes the execute method as expected and skips straight to the getChart() method. So the real question is why does it skip straight to that instead of doing the entire class like any other action I have?

Comment: Because your `execute` method is named `exectue`?

Comment: well I'll be damned that was a dumb mistake.